# How to calculate with $\lceil \cdot \rceil$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have a problem calculating with ceils.

If I have $\frac{\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil}{np}$, this is not the same as $\frac{\lceil \frac{1}{2} \rceil}{p}$.

Are there some rules on how to calculate with these things in order to be able to divide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, (assuming $n$ is an integer) either $n$ is even or odd, so for some integer $k$ either 
$$ n=2k, \qquad \frac{\lceil n/2\rceil}{np} = \frac{1}{2p}, $$
or
$$ n=2k+1, \qquad \frac{\lceil n/2\rceil}{np} = \frac{k+1}{(2k+1)p}. $$

In general, for $\frac{\lceil \alpha n\rceil}{np}$, the best you can do is say that because you know that
$$ x \leq \lceil x\rceil < x+1, $$
you can pick a real number $0\leq \theta<1$, so that
$$ \lceil \alpha n\rceil = \alpha n+\theta, \qquad \frac{\lceil \alpha n\rceil}{np} = \frac{\alpha}{p} + \frac{\theta}{n p}, $$
where the only thing known about $\theta$ is that $0\leq \theta<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Floors are generally nicer than ceilings. So, note that $\lceil x \rceil= -\lfloor -x \rfloor$.

Also note that $x = \lfloor x\rfloor + \{x\}$, where $\{x\}$ is the *fractional part* of $x$.

Then, your case is:
\begin{align}
\frac{\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil}{np} &= \frac{-\lfloor -\frac{n}{2} \rfloor}{np}\\
&= \frac{-\left(-\frac{n}{2}-\left\{-\frac{n}{2}\right\}\right)}{np}\\
&= \frac{n}{2np}+\frac{\left\{-\frac{n}{2}\right\})}{np}\\
&= \frac{1}{2p}+\frac{\left\{-\frac{n}{2}\right\}}{np}\\
\end{align}

If $n$ is a real number, this is about as far as you can go.